# if i<=number-1 then, maximum value of i should be number-1, then how number%1==0 or i==number statements are true?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

i whose maximum value is number-1, Is still satisfying those equations.Because i cannot be equal to number.

```
for (i = 2; i <=number-1; i++)
   if(number%i==0)
    break;
    if(i==number){
        cout<<"This is a prime number";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Not prime number";
    }
```

Comment: the loop ceases iterating when i>number-1, which is when i==number.

Comment: Your indentation is misleading. `if (i==number)` is actually outside the loop.

Comment: Don't you need to enclose all the lines after the for loop in braces ?

Comment: @auburg it's a working sieve as written. Asker just doesn't understand how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop statement is defined in your code snippet the following way

```
for (i = 2; i <=number-1; i++)
   if(number%i==0)
    break;
```

That is it is the same as

```
for (i = 2; i <=number-1; i++)
{
   if(number%i==0) break;
}
```

The following if statement does not belong to the for loop

```
if(i==number){
    cout<<"This is a prime number";
}
else{
    cout<<"Not prime number";
}
```

So if after the for loop i is equal to number (after the last iteration of the loop) then the number is prime.

The reason of confusion is the bad formatting of the code.:)

Comment: Wait i==number statement needs i should be equal to number. but i = to number - 1?same as number%i==0.

Comment: @RaviArya After the last iteration of the loop i becomes equal to number and the condition i <=number-1 evaluates to false. So the loop stops its iterations. That is the loop stops iterations after i becomes equal to number.

Comment: @RaviArya The `if (i == number)` happens _after_ the loop stops. The loop stops _because_ `i == number`, which is the first `i` that does not fulfill `<= number-1`.